# php file_get_contents('php://input') returns null

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a custom rest api in wordpress which should get some data from user and then return some data to the user. But the problem is when user tries to send more than one parameter, the function does not workd properly the entered parameter becomes null.

this is the function which is responsible for getting user parameters and returning data:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
wp_send_json($data); // this is a wordpress default function
```

this function returns the entered parameters from user.
when I try to send a data like `{"title":"a custom title"}` using Postman or other online tools , the function works properly but when I try to send more than one parameter like `{"title":"custom title"},{"content":"some content"}` the function returns null. What should I do?